# Customizing elements

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I am trying to learn to create customized elements.  I'm starting with a navigation bar and am simply trying to make a class for a red navigation bar.

I create a class that extends UINavigationBar and have this code inside:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
        self.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return self;            
}
```

So lets see in my scene I have a view.  I add a navigation bar with interface builder and set its class to use my new class above.  However the colors are not changed.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want to change navigation bar color...

Comment: If you want all navbars to be red, why not call `[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor redColor];` at the start of your app?

Comment: @rmaddy this is just an example im working on - i am trying to learn how to customize elements.  later i will want customize buttons.  i am trying to learn how to do this with separate classes.

Comment: OK. Have you verified that `initWithFrame:` is actually called? With IB, most likely the `initWithCoder:` is called instead.

Comment: @rmaddy yeah i threw in an NSLog message, its definitely being called.

Answer (score 1):

The modifications have to be made in the drawRect function.  For example, what I ended up doing was:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents( [color CGColor]));
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    self.tintColor = color;
}
```